# Sphinx connection between two documentations

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am working on a documentation for some python project. I am having problem with connection two or more documentations - I have three Sphinx projects ( documentations ) and I want to be able to add links to detailed docs in general doc.

I have such a project structure:

```
project/
|     doc/                          # this is my general doc
|     |    source/                  # sphinx general doc .rst files are here
|     |     build/
|     |    _static/
|     |    _templates/
|     |    CVS/
|
|
|     forms/
|     |    doc/
|     |    |    source/             # sphinx forms doc .rst files are here
|     |    |     build/
|     |    |    _static/
|     |    |    _templates/
|     |    |    CVS/    
|     |     
|     |    src/                     # forms source .py files are here
|
|     tables/
|     |    doc/
|     |    |    source/             # sphinx tables doc .rst files are here
|     |    |     build/
|     |    |    _static/
|     |    |    _templates/
|     |    |    CVS/    
|     |     
|     |    src/                     # tables source .py files are here
```

Both Forms doc and Tables doc contain documentation generated from source files with use of

**.. automodule::** directive.

How can I create links to Forms and Tables docs in my general documentation ?

Maybe I need to reorganize something?

I've already read a bit about intersphinx, but so far I've found examples that only show how to link to

Python standard library documentation by specifing URL in sphinx project's conf.py file like this :

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('http://docs.python.org/3.2', None)}
```

I don't know how to create such a thing with something diffrent than Standard library and I 
want to

specify its location **by relative path and not URL** - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The location in the intersphinx config (in your example 'http://docs.python.org/3.2') can actually be any URI or path to a directory where there is a file named objects.inv, which is created by the HTML builder and contains a registry of names and links.  Try using something like '../forms/_build/html'.